# Prove that given kernel is valid and find the relevant mapping

Tags: machine-learning, kernel-trick

*Understanding Machine Learning: From Theory to Algorithms*, Section 16.6, Question 4 is

[image]

[image]

For $x>z$, I formulate my kernel matrix as $K = [x \quad z;z \quad z]$ which gives the cofactors as $x, z(x-z) > 0$ and thus positive definite. I apply a similar rationale for the $x<z$ case.

I'm struggling with finding the mapping $\psi$. Any pointers on how to go about it?